# What do size-extensivity and size-consistency mean?

Tags: hartree-fock, coupled-cluster, binding-energy, configuration-interaction, many-body-perturbation-theory

I have heard both terms in various lectures and books on quantum chemistry, however, I have not found a proper explanation of them. As I understand now, size consistency of a method means for example, that the energy of two molecules separated by an infinite distance is the same as the sum of the energies individually calculated on each. Size extensivity seems to be about whether the method scales linearly (?) with the number of electrons.

What is confusing is that sometimes these terms are used to mean the same thing, in lectures or presentations. I am really unsure about which methods are size consistent and which are size extensive and which are not.

Comment: +1. I've commented out the "Which of these method have which properties and why?" question because it's a different question, but it could work well in the [tag:one-topic-per-answer] format if you were to post it as a separate question: each answer could give a proof of why a particular method is (or isn't) size-consistent or size-extensive. I'll consult with some others [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113019/meta-matters) before encouraging this though!

Comment: I think it is a bit senmantic. In https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00214-013-1440-y, appendix, Q1, the authors thought they are the same.

Answer (score 7):

**Size-consistency**: Your description is correct. $E_{AB}(r=\infty) = E_A + E_B$.

**Size-extensivity:** I explained this in my answer ["Constraint #13: Size-Extensivity"](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1329/5) to the question asking for the 17 different constraints for the  SCAN functional.

> "What is confusing is that sometimes these terms are used to mean the same thing."

That's true. Based on my experience, what you have observed happens because the vast majority of quantum chemists do not really know what these terms mean. Size-consistency is largely known, but I've seen some of the best experts in the field (people who did their PhD exclusively on developing coupled cluster methods) who don't quite know what size-extensivity means, or frequently confuse the two, or would frequently need to look up the definitions to remind themselves of the meanings.